# Convert multi line txt data to a CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is a sample of my data.

```
TRANS,"GUS000017787609","","","INSTL","","","","","","",,"","",20211025,
MTPNT,"",45654,"","","","","",,,
ASSET,"","INSTL","METER","","CR","G4SZV-2","FLN",2020,"XXXTYU422000","32","","LI"
```

I need to somehow turn this kind of information in a CSV using python. I've got thousands of rows of data and each TRANS,MTPNT and ASSET is considered one "row".

Does anyone know what the best type of technique would be to preform ETL on data of this kind?

Comment: That's already a CSV file. What do you mean by convert it to CSV?

Comment: Maybe the OP would like to merge programmatically that 3-row pattern in one row in a large file, and then produce a new CSV (AFAIU)

Comment: You can use the `csv` library to read and write CSV files. You can also use `pandas.read_csv()` and `pandas.to_csv()` to convert between CSV and Pandas dataframes.

Comment: @flotingpurr yes, exactly that! Sorry for not fully explaining , I would like alter the data from the 3 row pattern and convert the data so it sits on one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=grouper#itertools-recipes) recipe to read 3 CSV lines at a time and combine them. For example:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    
    
with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:    
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    
    for triple_row in grouper(csv_input, 3, ''):
        row = list(chain.from_iterable(triple_row))
        #row[2] = 'test'      # modify 3rd value before writing  
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you:

```
TRANS,GUS000017787609,,,INSTL,,,,,,,,,,20211025,,MTPNT,,45654,,,,,,,,,ASSET,,INSTL,METER,,CR,G4SZV-2,FLN,2020,XXXTYU422000,32,,LI
```

Comment: That sounds to be a great place to start! And once its on one line, i can start adding columns to each comma separation value.

Comment: Im getting some 'NoneType' object is not iterable? And i cant see why as i have no misisng data as far as im aware

Comment: If you add `print(triple_row)` you will probably find it relates to the last entries in your file. If there are not an exact number of triple rows it would produce `None`. The solution is to add the fillvalue in the grouper call. I have updated it